# bash: http-server: command not found

Tags: angularjs, npm

I am trying to run AngularJS project. I am unable to start the http server. I have tried multiple solution posted in the past.

When perform `npm list --depth=0` got following error on my project path

```
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY grunt@^0.4.5
├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY grunt-angular-templates@1.2.0
│ └── html-minifier@4.0.0
├── grunt-concurrent@3.0.0
├── grunt-contrib-clean@2.0.0
├── grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1
├── grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0
├── grunt-contrib-cssmin@3.0.0
├── grunt-contrib-htmlmin@3.1.0
├── grunt-contrib-uglify@4.0.1
├── grunt-cssbeautifier@0.1.2
├── grunt-jsbeautifier@0.2.13
├── grunt-ng-annotate@3.0.0
└── grunt-notify@0.4.5

npm ERR! missing: grunt-angular-templates@1.2.0, required by hrms-public@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: grunt@^0.4.5, required by hrms-public@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: html-minifier@4.0.0, required by grunt-angular-templates@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: clean-css@4.2.1, required by html-minifier@4.0.0
npm ERR! missing: commander@2.20.1, required by html-minifier@4.0.0
npm ERR! missing: he@1.2.0, required by html-minifier@4.0.0
npm ERR! missing: uglify-js@3.6.0, required by html-minifier@4.0.0
npm ERR! missing: upper-case@1.1.3, required by camel-case@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: source-map@0.6.1, required by clean-css@4.2.1
npm ERR! missing: commander@2.20.1, required by uglify-js@3.6.0
npm ERR! missing: source-map@0.6.1, required by uglify-js@3.6.0
npm ERR! missing: xtend@4.0.1, required by through2@2.0.5
npm ERR! missing: core-util-is@1.0.2, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: util-deprecate@1.0.2, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: lodash@4.17.15, required by async@2.6.2
npm ERR! missing: file-sync-cmp@0.1.1, required by grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: uri-path@1.0.0, required by grunt-contrib-uglify@4.0.1
npm ERR! missing: cssbeautify@0.3.1, required by grunt-cssbeautifier@0.1.2
npm ERR! missing: grunt@0.4.5, required by grunt-cssbeautifier@0.1.2
npm ERR! missing: async@0.1.22, required by grunt@0.4.5
npm ERR! missing: nopt@1.0.10, required by grunt@0.4.5
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.2.8, required by grunt@0.4.5
npm ERR! missing: grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3, required by grunt@0.4.5
npm ERR! missing: lru-cache@2.7.3, required by minimatch@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: lodash@2.4.2, required by grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3
npm ERR! missing: underscore.string@2.3.3, required by grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3
npm ERR! missing: lru-cache@2.7.3, required by minimatch@0.2.14
npm ERR! missing: grunt@1.0.4, required by grunt-jsbeautifier@0.2.13
npm ERR! missing: lodash@4.17.15, required by grunt-jsbeautifier@0.2.13
npm ERR! missing: lodash@4.17.15, required by async@2.6.2
npm ERR! missing: coffeescript@1.10.0, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: dateformat@1.0.12, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: findup-sync@0.3.0, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: glob@7.0.6, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: grunt-legacy-log@2.0.0, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: grunt-legacy-util@1.1.1, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: grunt-cli@1.2.0, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: iconv-lite@0.4.24, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: js-yaml@3.13.1, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: nopt@3.0.6, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: grunt-known-options@1.1.1, required by grunt@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: meow@3.7.0, required by dateformat@1.0.12
npm ERR! missing: camelcase-keys@2.1.0, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: loud-rejection@1.6.0, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@1.2.0, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: normalize-package-data@2.5.0, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: read-pkg-up@1.0.1, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: redent@1.0.0, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: trim-newlines@1.0.0, required by meow@3.7.0
npm ERR! missing: camelcase@2.1.1, required by camelcase-keys@2.1.0
npm ERR! missing: currently-unhandled@0.4.1, required by loud-rejection@1.6.0
npm ERR! missing: signal-exit@3.0.2, required by loud-rejection@1.6.0
npm ERR! missing: array-find-index@1.0.2, required by currently-unhandled@0.4.1
npm ERR! missing: hosted-git-info@2.8.4, required by normalize-package-data@2.5.0
npm ERR! missing: resolve@1.12.0, required by normalize-package-data@2.5.0
npm ERR! missing: validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4, required by normalize-package-data@2.5.0
npm ERR! missing: path-parse@1.0.6, required by resolve@1.12.0
npm ERR! missing: spdx-correct@3.1.0, required by validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0, required by validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0, required by spdx-correct@3.1.0
npm ERR! missing: spdx-license-ids@3.0.5, required by spdx-correct@3.1.0
npm ERR! missing: spdx-exceptions@2.2.0, required by spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: spdx-license-ids@3.0.5, required by spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: find-up@1.1.2, required by read-pkg-up@1.0.1
npm ERR! missing: read-pkg@1.1.0, required by read-pkg-up@1.0.1
npm ERR! missing: path-exists@2.1.0, required by find-up@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: pinkie-promise@2.0.1, required by find-up@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: pinkie-promise@2.0.1, required by path-exists@2.1.0
npm ERR! missing: pinkie@2.0.4, required by pinkie-promise@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: load-json-file@1.1.0, required by read-pkg@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: normalize-package-data@2.5.0, required by read-pkg@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: path-type@1.1.0, required by read-pkg@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: graceful-fs@4.2.2, required by load-json-file@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: parse-json@2.2.0, required by load-json-file@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: pify@2.3.0, required by load-json-file@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: pinkie-promise@2.0.1, required by load-json-file@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: strip-bom@2.0.0, required by load-json-file@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: error-ex@1.3.2, required by parse-json@2.2.0
npm ERR! missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1, required by error-ex@1.3.2
npm ERR! missing: is-utf8@0.2.1, required by strip-bom@2.0.0
npm ERR! missing: graceful-fs@4.2.2, required by path-type@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: pify@2.3.0, required by path-type@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: pinkie-promise@2.0.1, required by path-type@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: indent-string@2.1.0, required by redent@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: strip-indent@1.0.1, required by redent@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: repeating@2.0.1, required by indent-string@2.1.0
npm ERR! missing: is-finite@1.0.2, required by repeating@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: glob@5.0.15, required by findup-sync@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@5.0.15
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.0.6
npm ERR! missing: colors@1.1.2, required by grunt-legacy-log@2.0.0
npm ERR! missing: grunt-legacy-log-utils@2.0.1, required by grunt-legacy-log@2.0.0
npm ERR! missing: lodash@4.17.15, required by grunt-legacy-log@2.0.0
npm ERR! missing: chalk@2.4.2, required by grunt-legacy-log-utils@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: lodash@4.17.15, required by grunt-legacy-log-utils@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1, required by chalk@2.4.2
npm ERR! missing: supports-color@5.5.0, required by chalk@2.4.2
npm ERR! missing: async@1.5.2, required by grunt-legacy-util@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: lodash@4.17.15, required by grunt-legacy-util@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: which@1.3.1, required by grunt-legacy-util@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: findup-sync@0.3.0, required by grunt-cli@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: nopt@3.0.6, required by grunt-cli@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: resolve@1.1.7, required by grunt-cli@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: grunt-known-options@1.1.1, required by grunt-cli@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: safer-buffer@2.1.2, required by iconv-lite@0.4.24
npm ERR! missing: argparse@1.0.10, required by js-yaml@3.13.1
npm ERR! missing: esprima@4.0.1, required by js-yaml@3.13.1
npm ERR! missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3, required by argparse@1.0.10
npm ERR! missing: util-deprecate@1.0.2, required by underscore.string@3.3.5
npm ERR! missing: acorn@2.6.4, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: alter@0.2.0, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: convert-source-map@1.1.3, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: ordered-ast-traverse@1.1.1, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: simple-fmt@0.1.0, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: simple-is@0.2.0, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: stringmap@0.2.2, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: stringset@0.2.1, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: tryor@0.1.2, required by ng-annotate@1.2.2
npm ERR! missing: ordered-esprima-props@1.1.0, required by ordered-ast-traverse@1.1.1
```

But when I perform the same command outside my project directory 
(default user library) getting following result.

```
└── (empty)



   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                │
   │       New minor version of npm available! 6.9.0 → 6.11.3       │
   │   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.11.3   │
   │               Run npm install -g npm to update!                │
   │                                                                │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

**Update**

Please find below screenshot for package.json file

[image]

Comment: please provide your package.json file

Comment: @parasshah added can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

first install all dependencies by at the path where your package.json file exists

```
npm install
```

and also

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

and  you can add grunt-serve by below command

```
npm install grunt-serve --save-dev
```

and serve command 
grunt serve

Comment: Not working. Getting same error while tried to start server